# Read each value one by one in a column with respect to another values in another column from a text file

Tags: python

For example, I have a text file like this. There are three columns.

```
data 5 0.1
data 4 0.2
data 2 0.3
data 1 0.5
```

Codes I have:

```
for line in open("myfile.txt", "r").readlines():
    line = line.split()
    if len(line)>1 and line[0] == 'data':
        time = line[1]
        volume = line[2]
        volume_per_time=float(volume)/float(time)
print(volume_per_time)
```

I want to print the volume_per_time in a while loop. i.e. I want to call the 3nd column 1st value with respect to 2nd column 1st value. And then one by one with loop function.

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Comment: Move the `print` inside the loop.

Comment: What does "with respect to" mean? What is the operation you would like to do with the volume_per_time for each row?

Comment: if i call 5 then the operation of 5/0.1 should be performed. then it should repeat for all the next rows.  4/0.2 and  2/0.3 and 1/0.5.

Comment: actually i wanted to plot a graph with the last two columns of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can insert the calculated value to an array and use it for the plotting.

```
volume_per_time = []
for line in open("myfile.txt", "r").readlines():
    line = line.split()
    if len(line)>1 and line[0] == 'data':
        time = line[1]
        volume = line[2]
        volume_per_time.append(float(volume)/float(time))

print(volume_per_time)
```